# pandas ffill() with groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe with 22 columns:

```
ID     S0     S1     S2 .....
ABC          10.4   5.58
ABC   12.6          
ABC                 8.45
LMN           5.6   
LMN   8.7
```

I have to ffill() the values based on groups. Intended result:

```
ID     SS     RR     S2   ...
ABC          10.4   5.58
ABC   12.6   10.4   5.58
ABC   12.6   10.4   8.45
LMN           5.6   
LMN   8.7     5.6
```

I am using the following code to get S0,S1... values:

```
df[['Resistance', 'cumcountR']].pivot(columns='cumcountR').droplevel(0, axis=1).add_prefix('R').drop(columns='R-1.0').ffill()
```

Little help will be appreciated. THANKS!

Comment: I guess the empty values are `NaN` in your actual data and not empty strings since these are numeric columns.

Answer (score 3):

Try with [`GroupBy.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ffill.html)

```
out = df.groupby('ID').ffill()
```

Comment: raise KeyError(gpr)
KeyError: 'ID'

Comment: I have added some info into the question